# Can I open Settings app from my app?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I want open notification(in Settings app) of my app.

**How can I do it?**

maybe someone have deals.

for example:

[a busy cat http://0.tqn.com/d/ipod/1/0/d/H/-/-/notification-center-settings.jpg](http://0.tqn.com/d/ipod/1/0/d/H/-/-/notification-center-settings.jpg)

**P.S. I use IOS 5.0, ... 6.1**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do that,it won't work as apple has not provided any details or `URL Schemes` related to opening settings app  in newer versions.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=NOTIFICATIONS_ID"]]
```

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work for ios >= 5.1. http://www.iphonehacks.com/2011/11/apple-disables-home-screen-shortcuts-for-settings-toggles-in-ios-5-1.html.

Comment: As far as I know, there's no way of doing this for ios >= 5.1

Comment: @Vit because it did work, but only on iOS 5.0 not on 5.1 or higher.

Comment: On iOS 5.0 it works and you said you were using iOS 5.0.

Comment: ok, i know worked it. but how do it on 5.1 and higher don't know anyone((

Answer (score -1):

You can do this on your [iPhone](http://itechbook.net)

by using this Code

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=NOTIFICATIONS_ID"]]
```